# How to force certain elements to only show when fully loaded on a webpage?

Tags: html

Lets take a static html page as a scenario, lets say you have a DIV element that you wish to only render fully within a users browser AFTER all its content has already been fully loaded instead of having bits and pieces of it appear. Any ideas appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the `DIV`s and show them with JavaScript when `onload` fires. E.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function showHidden() {
        document.getElementById("cantseeme").style.display='block'; // Show it
      }
    </script> 
  </head>

  <body onload="showHidden();">
    <div id="cantseeme" style="display:none;">Hidden element</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No problem and thanks. JavaScript always comes handy when you need to modify the page in one way or another. :)

Comment: Rather than using onload, if you put the script at the very end of the file, after the body, wouldn't that achieve the same effect?

Comment: @Will - Putting it at the end might trigger while images and objects are still loading. That's why it's better to trigger it `onload`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery, the DIV would have a style of display:none, and my body onLoad function would set the display to block.

Answer (score 0):

trigger your code after the dom ready event. [Link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domready.shtml) here for more details.